# getMap() method in new Android API is not working properly for me

Tags: java, android

Sample code:

```
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mMap = mapFragment.getMap();
```

but it is not working as expected.

Then I replace `getMapAsync(this)method`. Still it´s not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to implement `OnMapReadyCallback`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

}
```

so code for onCreate() will be

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

and overrided method `onMapReady()` will look like below

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
}
```